What does the yellow text and circle in the outline of a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code indicate?
I've encountered an unusual feature in Visual Studio Code while working with a Jupyter Notebook. In the notebook's outline pane, some sections are marked with yellow text and an adjacent yellow circle (see screenshot below).
This seems to be a new or undocumented feature, and I haven't been able to find an explanation for what this indicates. It does not appear to be a syntax or linting warning, nor does it resemble any typical highlight associated with code cells or markdown.
Has anyone else experienced this, and can provide insight into what these yellow markers signify? Is this related to any recent updates to the Jupyter extension for VS Code or a feature toggle that I might not be aware of?
Any guidance or references to documentation would be greatly appreciated.


Versions

VSCode: 1.89.0
Python extension: v2024.6.0
Jupyter extension: v2024.4.0
Python interpreter: 3.11.5

Extension bisect shows that it's Pylance that causes the problem.
Here is the result of running code --list:

aperricone.vscode-dbf
asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode
autodesk.autolispext
batisteo.vscode-django
bito.bito
chrmarti.regex
codium.codium
cschlosser.doxdocgen
cweijan.dbclient-jdbc
cweijan.vscode-autohotkey-plus
cweijan.vscode-postgresql-client2
devsense.composer-php-vscode
devsense.intelli-php-vscode
devsense.phptools-vscode
devsense.profiler-php-vscode
dnicolson.binary-plist
dotjoshjohnson.xml
ex-codes.pine-script-syntax-highlighter
formulahendry.code-runner
github.copilot
github.copilot-chat
ionutvmi.reg
jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax
mark-wiemer.vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus
mechatroner.rainbow-csv
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-python.debugpy
ms-python.isort
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode.cmake-tools
ms-vscode.cpptools
ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack
ms-vscode.cpptools-themes
ms-vscode.hexeditor
ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly
ms-vscode.powershell
ms-vscode.remote-explorer
ms-vscode.vscode-speech
nilssoderman.batch-runner
oderwat.indent-rainbow
qiaojie.binary-viewer
randomfractalsinc.vscode-data-preview
redhat.vscode-yaml
reditorsupport.r
ritwickdey.liveserver
shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced
twxs.cmake
yzhang.markdown-all-in-one
zainchen.json
zero-plusplus.vscode-autohotkey-debug



please edit your post to add the version number of your jupyter and python extensions. also your python interpreter version or whatever your kernel/s python interpreter version is. 2) try an extension bisect (not sure if it'll help here, since you'll presumably need the jupyter and python extension enabled at all times, but worth a shot). and add the output of running code --list-extensions to your post


It seems you are using a version control system(vcs) like git and this persumably shows that your files are modified since last change

so when you disable pylance, what does it look like?


It does not appear to be a syntax or linting warning, nor does it resemble any typical highlight associated with code cells or markdown.

For me, it does, the sections written in color show there is a code cell with a warning or an error (I also use Pylance).
For example, here I don't have error or warning :

With a warning, I have an orange text and an orange circle :

With an error, I have a red text and a red circle :


(note: here i'm not using any version control system like git)
